# Is it possible to retrieve listbox item IDs which are bound to a database table?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a program which has a creating meeting attendees function wherein I use a listbox in creating the attendance. The names are stored in a separate database table wherein I just fill-up a textbox and use an Add button for the name to be stored in the listbox.  Now, my problem is how do I retrieve the ID's of the names of those people that are in the listbox which are bound to a database (members table).

I am expecting that when I save the listbox, the database will be filled up like this:

```
attendeeid    |    memberid    |    membername    |
    1         |       1        |    Obama         |
    2         |       2        |    Franklin      |
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you're after here.  If you want to lookup the `IDs` of people in the `members` table, you can just do `SELECT attendeeid FROM members`.  What is the `DDL` of this table -- are there more fields to differentiate between different meetings?

Comment: What I am trying to do is when I will be saving the listbox items, I want to retrieve the ID's of the items that are bound in the database table.

Comment: By "bound" do you mean "committed and stored" in a table on the database?  Do you want to save the results and then retrieve them all in one `SQL` request?

Comment: Yes sir. That's exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: I don't know if MySql will let you chain statements like this together.  It's probably easiest to just do them as two separate statements.  If you want to, you could write a stored procedure, but that seems overkill.